# How do I get custom posts belonging to 2 categories with query_posts()?

Tags: wordpress

I have seen examples of how to get Custom posts in either of several categories using an array. I have seen how to create an "**and**" query for regular posts categories.  But, I would like to get custom posts by post type where the categories must be in category1 and in category2.  For example I have written:

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'cars', 'custom_category1' => 'Honda', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ));
```

This query works as I expect. However, some of the posts also belong to another category in that same post type - let's say "Accord" and I would like to list those posts.  So I want to list posts only if they are in both categories (Honda and Accord).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you try using the in_category function that might work. I think it could be in something like this `<?php if(in_category('honda') && in_category('accord') ): do something here endif; ?>`  hopefully this work. Please keep I've did not try this out.

Comment: Thanks, I will play with it and let you know.